# How to create Cron for job In one day

Tags: unix, cron

I need to create a cron job "in one day" and this job run like `25, 27, 29, 31, 2, 4...30, 2, 4....30, 1, 3`. How Can I do it? Thanks!

`Cron 0 0 0 1/2 * *` is wrong `(27, 29, 31, 1, 3)`

Comment: be more specific in what you want. also: why did you mark this to be java related?

Comment: What do you mean with "cron in one day"? What are those numbers? What SO are you using specifically?

Comment: I use it with java library Omnicron and it have to work with it. But I will be grateful for any help

Comment: I wrote example for day numbers

Comment: so, every other day?

Comment: Just check this link, the accepted answer shows what you need. https://serverfault.com/questions/204265/how-to-configure-cron-job-to-run-every-2-days-at-11pm

Comment: Yes, I think it's same

Comment: It not works for me, because  0 0 0 */2 * * works by days like 27, 29, 31, 1, 3. (31 and 1 is not every other day). I need to have situation like 31, 2, 4

Comment: If I understand this question well, you want to run your crontask every two days starting from some point of time. I believe it's not possible in single statement but you can try to write few independent statements, i.e. "run task every odd day in even month", "run task every even day in odd month", with some exceptions.
Anyways, I suggest to simplify things a little and just write a cron to run everyday and move the day check to the application you're going to execute.

Comment: The second answer in the link given by Stultuske is going to work. Since you didn't give us much context, we don't know if a shell script is what you are running or if this is something else. The point is: you have to use a temporary file or some other "marker", and run every day.